# How to get my Ethernet to work?

Tags: ethernet

This seems like a stupid question, but really how do I fix my Ethernet connection on my Dell N5010 laptop. So far I have tried latest Ubuntu and Mint, but I had same problem with both - Ethernet connection is stuck on a loop connecting -> disconnected -> connecting.

Of course I googled around and found that the driver r8169 for my Ethernet adapter (device manager shows Realtek 8101e/8102e) might be faulty. So I did my research, blacklisted r8169 and tried both r8168 and r8101, but nothing changed at all. Same connection loop.

Wireless network works just fine, but as this laptop's battery is dead, I don't carry it around at all. The one time I took it to my job (don't have wireless at home) Ubuntu downloaded tons of updates, but wired connection still wasn't working.

Other things I have tried like using different Ethernet cable and checking BIOS for some weird settings, but nothing has helped.

I remember a few years ago I tested Ubuntu 12 and at the wired connection worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Realtk Linux driver that was recently updated in September 2014...

http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=7&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2

Installation instructions are in `/r8101-1.026.00/readme` after you untar the `r8101-1.026.00.tar.bz2` download.